# Prevent activity from restarting on phone boot?

Tags: android

If a user reboots their phone while my activity is in the foreground, after the phone reboots, the activity automatically pops up again. I don't want this to happen because none of the extra data I pass to the activity is saved, so the activity does not have the correct display.

Apparently the activity is started even before my BroadcastReceiver that has an intent-filter with `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` starts.

How would I go about preventing the activity from automatically starting when the phone boots?

**Edit:** I use the `android.intent.category.HOME` category in my intent filter for my activity, which apparently is the reason for it starting up on reboot.

Comment: Nothing in Android will automatically restart your activity on a reboot, unless it is the home screen. Either your home screen is doing that, or you are doing that -- not Android.

Comment: Aha! That's part of the problem then. I use the category `android.intent.category.HOME` for this activity. Is there any way to disable this activity on reboot before it starts, or check if it started inside of the activity due to a phone restart?

Comment: "I use the category android.intent.category.HOME for this activity" -- then you are a home screen, and if the user set you as the default home screen, you *should* start on a reboot. "Is there any way to disable this activity on reboot before it starts" -- I suppose you could try listening for `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` broadcasts, then use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to disable the activity... but then something will need to re-enable it later.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try it out. On reboot, I have another service that starts up and sends the correct data to the home screen activity while restarting it, so have no fear, it will start on reboot, it will just be a bit delayed.

Comment: Your ACTION_SHUTDOWN and setComponentEnabledSetting() answer worked! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` broadcast is supposed to go out when the device is shutting down. I say "supposed to go out", because it assumes an orderly shutdown. If the user winds up holding the POWER button for ~10 seconds, or popping out the battery, I would assume that `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` is not broadcast.

To control whether a component (e.g., activity) is available, you can use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. A disabled component cannot be run and is generally invisible (e.g., a disabled app widget's `<receiver>` will not show up in the app widget picker).

In theory, you can combine these two. However, even at the best of times, I would assume that `ACTION_SHUTDOWN` behaviors are rather time-limited (so be quick about it), and you will need to handle the "disorderly" shutdown scenarios.